# Is there any way to send html reports with all the files and css embedded in the body of the email rather than attachment in jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

See the image, it misses out on some CSS - 
[image]

Comment: no, cannot. you have to add all files to archive and send. but it's bad way. You can send the URL of report.

Answer (score 0):

If report includes external or internal CSS, you try to convert them into inline css,  then the mail will display with style,  we did this by a nodejs package: [inline-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css)

If report includes external image, you can try to replace the image src with data url like: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,xxxxxxxxxxxx`, you can search maybe there is some tool can did that for you.

[Image data url](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/convert-an-image-to-a-data-uri-with-your-browser) for reference.

Another things need to consider, after convert image to data url and css to inline css, the report file size will increase and exceed your mailbox attachment file size limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Including the image data in the URI never worked well for me when embedding the report in an email.  Why not just reference the image URLs off the maven site instead.  Like this....

```css
img[src*="warning_sml.gif"]{content:url(http://maven.apache.org/images/icon_warning_sml.gif) !important;}
img[src*="error_sml.gif"]{content:url(http://maven.apache.org/images/icon_error_sml.gif) !important;}
img[src*="success_sml.gif"]{content:url(http://maven.apache.org/images/icon_success_sml.gif) !important;}
img[src*="maven-feather.png"]{content:url(http://maven.apache.org/images/logos/maven-feather.png) !important;}
```